# Java Count Words IndexOf

Tags: java, loops, count, while-loop, indexof

I'm trying to use simply a while loop and the String method `indexOf()` to count how many times a certain word appears in a String given by the user.

The method I created seems to count how many times a certain letter appears, but not how many times a word appears. I think this is because the indexOf can't differentiate between a set of letters and spaces. So would I have to create another loop for the computer to understand what I consider words?

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void countWord(String sentenceEntered, String badWord){

  int number =  sentenceEntered.toUpperCase().indexOf(badWord, 0);
  while (number >= 0){
    System.out.print(number);
   number = sentenceEntered.indexOf(badWord, number + 1);
   }


}//end of countWord
```

But when I run my program, nothing gets printed.

Comment: Give us an example please

Comment: A call example with a sentence and a badword

Comment: For instance, if the user input was: "Dope, I don't understand." And the bad word was "Dope", nothing would get printed.
But if I were to say, the bad word was "D", then [0,8,16,23] would be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems in your method:

1. The code converts the sentence to uppercase, but not the input word. Also in the `while` loop, the sentence is not converted to uppercase. So there is an inconsistency here.
2. The offset in the call to `String#indexOf` should be the previous index plus the length of the word, i.e. `number + badWord.length()` instead of `number +  1`.

   ```
   number = sentenceEntered.indexOf(badWord, number + badWord.length());
   ```

So after the changes, and assuming you no conversion to uppercase is done, the method should be as follows:

```
public static void countWord(String sentenceEntered, String badWord) {

    int number = sentenceEntered.indexOf(badWord, 0);
    while (number >= 0) {
        System.out.println(number);
        number = sentenceEntered.indexOf(badWord, number + badWord.length());
    }

}// end of countWord
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why though all of the words have to be uppercase in order for this method to work?

Comment: It's up to your program requirements to decide if the strings should be converted to uppercase. If you want the method to match the word in case-insensitive manner, then you should convert both `sentenceEntered` and `badWord`.

Answer (score 0):

You should uppercase your badword too.

```
int number =  sentenceEntered.toUpperCase().indexOf(badWord.toUpperCase(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to set the new starting index to number + badWord.length() in the while loop so that you can start the next indexOf at the end of the last badWord.

```
number = sentenceEntered.indexOf(badWord, number + badWord.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what is causing your current issue, if you just want to count the number of word occurence in a sentence, there's a simple way without using the loops

```
int length = sentenceEntered.length();
int badwordLength = badword.length();
if (sentenceEntered.contains(badword)) {
      System.out.println("badword count: " + (length - sentenceEntered.replace(badword,"").length() / badwordLength));
}
```